# codeigniter+getting error on using nusoap library

Tags: codeigniter, nusoap

i am doing a call using nusoap library, but unfortunatly i am getting this error

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: lib/nusoap.php

Line Number: 3125

Answer (score -1):

By check on line no - 3125, you can see that this error is because of curl error.

 You need to debug this one by one.